# laravel eloquen fucntion with() get only 3 columns from relation 2 tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I need the id_jornada, nombre_jornada and the relation school: nombre_colegio but this last concat "nombre_jornada + nombre_colegio"

**jornadaController**

```
public function index(){
    $res = Jornada::where('estado', 1)->with('school:id,nombre_colegio')->get();

    return response()->json($res);
}
```

**axios response**

```
[
   {
      "id_jornada":1,
      "school_id":1,
      "nombre_jornada":"Matutina",
      "estado":1,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":"2021-02-05T21:19:17.000000Z",
      "school":{
         "id":1,
         "nombre_colegio":"La pradera"
      }
   },
   {
      "id_jornada":3,
      "school_id":7,
      "nombre_jornada":"Vespertina",
      "estado":1,
      "created_at":"2021-02-05T23:26:12.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-02-06T00:09:45.000000Z",
      "school":{
         "id":7,
         "nombre_colegio":"La pradera"
      }
   }
]
```

**but I need just like this.**

```
{
  "id_jornada":[
      "nombre_jornada + nombre_colegio",
    ]
}
```

**json**

```
{
  "1":[
      "Matutina La pradera",
    ],
  "3":[
      "Vespertina La pradera",
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `foreach` and make that array

```php
public function index()
{
    $jornada = Jornada::where('estado', 1)->with('school:id,nombre_colegio')->get();
    $result = [];
    foreach ($jornada as $row) {
        $res[] = $row->nombre_jornada . ' ' . $row->school->nombre_colegio ?? "";
    }

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

Comment: work so so but i need the key custom, is id_jornada. how can i do? response `["Matutina La pradera", "Vespertina La pradera"] `
`0: "Matutina La pradera"`
`1: "Vespertina La pradera"`

Comment: can u check now this is your looking?

Comment: not, return `0: "Matutina La pradera"`
`1: "Vespertina La pradera`

Comment: you want to return array ?

Comment: i need also the key in your firts answer just I need the custom key but you gave me a idea. i can do with collection and 2d idea using foreach.` $ob =  array();

            foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
                $ob[$value['id']] = $value['nombre_jornada']. ' ' . $value['sede']['nombre_colegio'];
            }

        return response()->json($ob);`